# Ubuntu 12.04 HP DV7 Suspend Works, Resume Doesn't

Tags: 12.04, suspend, hp, hp-pavilion

So my issue is that the suspension works, but once I resume, it will just stay in a black screen. Closing and opening the lid does nothing. I tried all sorts of things already with no luck. Can anyone see where the issue lies?

These are my specs:

- HP Pavilion dv7t-4000 CTO Select Edition
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-720QM Quad Core processor
- 1GB ATI Mobility Radeon(TM) HD 5650 [HDMI, VGA]
- Intel Wireless-N Card with Bluetooth

You can see some of my logs here:

http://rclai89.koding.com/specs.html

There I listed the pm-suspend.log, syslog and code I used on the 20_custom-ehci_hcd file from here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11926504 and made it easy to navigate thanks to CSS and some HTML tricks.

This is my current kernel build: 3.2.0-35-generic 64-bit

And my fglrx version: 9.002 (I downloaded the drivers from the AMD support page)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

**Edit:**

Oh wow, this is weird, it's now working. What happened was, I re-installed Ubuntu. What I did differently.

I auto-updated everything and kept my kernel 3.2.0-35-generic installation, I did not update to 3.4.

What I did differently is instead of installing the graphics drivers from AMD, I installed the graphics using

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

So now my fglrx version is 8.960.

While my suspension works, I notice that resuming will start up the screen on the lowest brightness setting, however once I hit the hotkeys to increase the brightness, the brightness goes back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the BIOS:

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00007682&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en

I  was having the same issue 10 minutes ago; flashing a new BIOS solved the problem.

Comment: Did you flash the BIOS in Ubuntu itself or did you have to do it in Windows?

Comment: I definitely had to do it in Windows, but if you're not currently dual booting you can install windows, flash bios, then reformat and get back to a pure linux box if you like.

Comment: I see.. do you have an HP laptop as well? I'm looking at the descriptions of the BIOS updates for my laptop and I'm not seeing anything relevant that may contribute to making the suspension work properly, unless they just left additional details out? http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4063&product=4186302&softwareitem=ob-100446-1&sw_lang=&